# Attempting to use moderncv, get wrong version of expl3 and l3kernel too old errors

Tags: errors, miktex, moderncv, expl3

I'm relatively new with LaTeX. I've been trying to use moderncv, but when I do I get the following errors:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 53, version
               `2013/07/28' of package exp13,
               but only version
               `2013/03/14 v4469 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper'
               is available.
! Package xparse Error: Support package l3kernel too old.
See the xparse package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
 ...

1.65   }
```

While there are many other errors, they seem to descent for the most part from this one.

I'm using TeXnicCenter to run MiKTeX 2.9 on a Windows machine. Below is a fairly minimal example code that encounters the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}


\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Is this likely to be due to a real bug with the packages involved, or is there likely something I forgot to load/didn't implement properly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! :) I'd say you need to update your TeX distribution. You seem to have different versions of `l3packages` (where `xparse` is part of) and `l3kernel` (which provides the `expl3` package and other parts of the l3kernel).

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks! Turns out it was just an update issue, as you guys suggested

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is fixed by running an update.